# Infinite realities: Theoretically if the sun burned out or if all resources were used up, in another universe could it have not happened at all?

Tags: reality, quantum-physics, universe, infinite

This is assuming that infinite realities exist. I have no physics or philosophy background, I am writing a science fiction novel. That being said, please dumb down your answers for me.

Comment: There may be a better SE to ask this question. I anticipate the question will be closed because it is too broad or opinion based, but don't be discouraged. Some other more focused question may work.

Comment: To add to Frank's comment, an actual SE for that would  be worldbuilding. But you'd need a bit more details.

Comment: A better place for imaginary sci-phi scenario questions is [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "maybe."

It is possible to create an infinite number of descriptions of realities which all have the same event (such as a resource being consumed).  It is also possible to create an infinite number of descriptions of realities where at least some of them do not have that event.  "Could" is a very wide open word in metaphysics, because we currently have no way of observing whether or not such other universes exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but minbendingly unlikely.

For scale, consider the gas molecules bouncing around in a pop bottle filled with air. There is a possibility that all the molecules will spontenously find themselves in just one half of the bottle, for a tiny fraction of a second. If you run the numbers, that won't happen on average even once, in the current age of the universe.

We think of the probability space of our universe, the set of 'parallel' worlds, as defined by a set of dimensionless physical constants https://www.forbes.com/sites/ethansiegel/2015/08/22/it-takes-26-fundamental-constants-to-give-us-our-universe-but-they-still-dont-give-everything/#5aba049b4b86 Then, at various points quantum uncertainties create different outcomes, especially impactful in the very early universe where fluctuations developed into the universes large scale structure.

We would expect identically similar universes to only be different by a few fluctuations. They might snowball into a comet hitting or just missing the earth (see Seveneves for example consequences). Maybe some process out there could result in a really stupidly powerful cosmic ray that could say trigger a small black hole, disrupting the sun's hydrogen burning temporarily.

Probabilities, in quantum mechanics and thermidynamics, are cornerstones of having a comprehensible world. To have not just one or even many different, but a towering compound chain of incredibly unlikely outcomes, seems against our experience, against what we know.

Try the World Building SE for further discussion. Maybe with context of *why* you are interested in this, alternatives can be found..